# Div scrolling inside map on apple

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I have a little problem. I'm cleaning some bugs on particular page. There on the right side is a map which has some markers. When you click on marker some info appears in a box. I have set that box to overflow: auto. The problem is: when you open that page in apple production, that box (which shows up by clicking on marker) doesn't scroll, whole website is scrolling. On androids everything is working fine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`

Useful materials:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements/

Comment: Thanks! I tried this code at the beginning, but it was directed to different html element. Thanks again!